# Sobolev spaces inclusion

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm having trouble finding an answer related to Sobolev spaces that does not relate to duality. I'm looking for an answer to the following question:

When (i.e. for what domains $\Omega$ or such) can we talk about an inclusion of the type:

$$ W^{m,p}(\Omega) \subset W^{n,p}(\Omega) \hspace{10px} \text{for} \hspace{10px} m>n$$

or, at least to me, of equal importance, and even more so if different from the conditions for the above:

$$ H^m(\Omega) \subset H^n(\Omega) \hspace{10px} \text{for} \hspace{10px} m>n$$

I appreciate any insight, or advice on where to read this up (sorry in advance if this is somewhere easily reachable online, but I haven't found it yet).

Comment: Isn't this true for all domains? If you have $m$ derivatives in $L^p$ then you have $n$ derivatives in $L^p$ ($m > n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for every domain $\Omega$ that we can define Sobolev spaces on.